# AWS: When I tried to update a item in dynamodb the following error appears The provided key element does not match the schema

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

When I tried to update a item in dynamodb the following error appears:

```
var docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();

function updateItem() {
    var table = "Bicycle";

    var params = {
        TableName:table,
        Key:{
            warrantyDate: "2018/10/23",
            warrantyStatus: "Active"
        },
        UpdateExpression: "set warrantyStatus = :r",
        ExpressionAttributeValues:{
            ":r":"Inactive"
        },
        ReturnValues:"UPDATED_NEW"
    };

    docClient.update(params, function(err, data) {
        if (err) {
            alert("Unable to update item");
             alert(err);
        } else {
            alert("UpdateItem succeeded");
        }
    });
}
```

when I call this function I received this exception:

**ValidationException: The provided key element does not match the schema**

how can i fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you KEY attribute value does not match your primary partition key on your dynamodb table.

When updating an item, you need to specify the **single key** that maps to your primary key on the dynamodb table. There should only be one attribute in the Key field. You are trying to find a key that is both the **warrantyDate** and **warrantyStatus**. Make sure you're specifying the correct key that maps to your dynamodb configuration.

If you're trying to update multiple items, you need to use another function, as **doClient.update()** only updates a single row that matches your **key** to the primary index on the table.